# HtmlWebpackPlugin + webpack-dev-server: why a script tag is not injected into page on localhost?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I try to implement injection of script tag with bundle into the page which is used by `webpack-dev-server`. I open localhost:3000 served by dev server, but there is no script tag inside. What the problem might be?

Here is project structure and configuration https://gist.github.com/web-worddoc/12ee225ae5e1194e0b04b6ecda70ec41

Comment: This version of the htmlwebpackplugin plugin 3.2.0 does not work with webpack 4, install ```html-webpack-plugin@next```

Comment: @Grzegorz T. Hmm, that is worthy note, thanks. But it still doesn't inject script tag